# Multiple collision events in Action Script 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, event-handling, if-statement, collision-detection

I am currently building a game, where u have controllers which you can move around and are connected one to another by lines, and the lines need to collide with all the eggs on the screen to go to the next level. Also, whenever an egg collides with a line, the egg changes its colour.

The thing is, I have about 10 eggs and 7 lines, and getting the conditionals for checking if the egg is touched by a line, and if all the eggs are touched by lines, is A LOT (I mean seriously  a lot I've already tried it) of code.

Its just stacking HUNDREDS of conditionals and event listeners together.

Does anybody have a prettier solution?
Thnx for any comments :D

Comment: are eggs and lines implementes as classes?

Comment: no. how do i make then into classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use nested for loops to check on enterframe event. This could eat up the processor, so make sure you only run the loop when necessary.

Here is a simple example of the nested loop:

```
var eggs:Array = [e0,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,e9];
var lines:Array = [l0,l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6];
var eggLen:int = eggs.length;
var lineLen:int  = lines.length;
var egg:MovieClip;
var line:MovieClip;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);

function enterFrameHandler(e:Event):void {
    EggLoop:for (var i:int = 0; i<eggLen; i++) {
        egg = eggs[i];
        LineLoop:for (var j:int = 0; j<lineLen; j++) {
            line = lines[j];
            if (egg.hitTestObject(line)) {
                trace("Egg: " + egg + " just hit Line: " + line);
                break LineLoop;
                // if you want to break the entire loop use:
                // break EggLoop;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: var eggs:Array = [e0,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,e9];
var lines:Array = [l0,l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6];
var eggLen:int = eggs.length;
var lineLen:int  = lines.length;
what are all these names (in the variables/ arrays)? di i need to change anything for it to work?

Comment: These would be the instance names of your eggs and lines. I just made up names as an example. If you replace the names in the array with the actual names of your instances, it should be test worthy. The 'eggLen' and 'lineLen' variables are just references to the length of the array. These references are used in the loop so Flash won't calculate the length on each enterframe event. It'll help performance.

Comment: Now Im going to use it for an AIR3.0 iPhone and android application. Will this REALLY eat up CPU and more importantly, battery?

Comment: Another thing: If i wanted to make a sound when an egg is being hit, but only once, how can i do that (I mean the trace() you add there just keep going on forever...). And, how can I check if all the eggs are collided with lines? Thank you for your help by the way!

Comment: The loop isn't that intense, but to be safe I would kill it anytime you don't need to run the hitTest. As for the sound, I don't know what the game concept is, so I'm not sure if the game ends when the first egg hits the first line...or, the first line that any egg hits. Either way, sounds like you could use conditionals and/or another array to store the "hit" objects. If the object is in the "hit" array, just skip over it.

Comment: so how can i update an array if an reg is hitter by the line? and how can i check if all of them are?